# How to recode variable to a categorical type based on list of row numbers

Tags: r

I am having trouble trying to create a new categorical variable in a data frame which is based on a pre-determined list of which rows in the data frame should be coded as 1 or 0.

I am trying to do this in a large dataset (174020x514) but for the sake of reproducibility for the concept I'll use the `mtcars` dataset. Essentially I have a vector containing a list of row numbers `x` I want to recode the data by.

```
df<-mtcars
cat=vector("numeric",length=nrow(df))
df<-cbind(df,cat)
x<-c(1,3,5,8,32)
df$cat[nrow(df)==x]<-1
df$cat[nrow(df)!=x]<-0
df$cat
```

So the result I want is that the row numbers 1,3,5,8 and 32 are coded as 1 in the new categorical column and the rest as 0. I was also having trouble using an `ifelse` statement because of the list `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your dataframe is large, maybe use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cat := 0L][x, cat := 1][, cat := as.factor(cat)]
```

We first create a column `cat` which is equal to zero by reference. Then, assign all rows in `x` to 1.

If `cat` is not required to be of `factor` class, just use this:

```
setDT(df)[, cat := 0L][x, cat := 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried using the data.table package but I ran into an issue when I used this for the actual large data set:
`Error in .data.table(setDT(ed0509)[, :=(SSTI.cat, 0)], SSTI.comb,  : 
  i[502] is 175234 which is out of range [1,nrow=174020].`

ed0509 is the dataframe, SSTI.cat is the new column variable and SSTI.comb is the equivalent of x.

Comment: The code is quite excessive, I can tell you what I've been trying to use...
`> str(SSTI.comb) num [1:770] 705 1829 2644 3368 3578 ...`
Is it because I have values in my vector >174020?
`> length(SSTI.comb) [1] 770`
`setDT(ed0509)[SSTI.comb,SSTI.cat:=1][,SSTI.cat:=0]`

Comment: `> tail(SSTI.comb)
[1] 508909 509160 511395 515337 516339 520598`

Comment: I do get an error. I realized that my problem is with my code prior to this where I'm using `grep()` to produce the list I'm using to subset, but it is giving back row values that are beyond that of the dataset I'm using, >174020. I'm trying to trouble shoot that right now.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df %<>% 
    mutate(cat = +(row_number() %in% x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df$cat[(1:32)%in%x]<-1
df$cat[!(1:32)%in%x]<-0
df$cat

[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x` to index your data.frame without having to hard code the number of rows:

```
df$cat[x] <- 1
df$cat[is.na(df$cat)] <- 0
```

Comment: Probably be more straightforward to assign everything to 0 first and then overwrite once - `df$cat <- 0; df$cat[x] <- 1`